# using Jasper reports in a PHP website

Tags: php, jasper-reports

I would like to use Java reports 'report engine' to generate reports (HTML/PDF etc) and display them on my website.

However, my website is using a PHP web framework. Can anyone suggest how I may be be able to use Jasper Reports within a PHP web framework?

Answer (score 9):

If you [checkout the PHP REST Client on Github](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jrs-rest-php-client), or add it to your PHP project via Composer you will be able to run a report through web services.

Your code should look something like:

```
<?php
    $c = new \Jaspersoft\Client\Client(
    "http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro",
    "jasperadmin",
    "jasperadmin",
    "organization_1"
  );

    $report = $c->reportService()->runReport('/reports/samples/AllAccounts', 'html');
    echo $report;       
?>
```

That would retrieve a report in HTML format and store it in `$report`. Of course you can change html to pdf or xls or whatever format you wish to export to.

If you wish to display PDFs or offer them for download, you will have to supply the binary data to some package that can handle it, or provide proper headers allowing it to be downloaded by a web browser.

I happen to be the one developing this package, so feel free to shoot me a line with any questions.

Comment: I did tries using same steps but got error like Jaspersoft\Exception\RESTRequestException: An unexpected HTTP status code was returned by the server in

Answer (score 3):

1. using PHP/Java Bridge(http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/).
2. deploy the Java Bridge on tomcat Server.
3. copy the jar jasper lib and mysql connector j lib in tomcat lib
4. restart tomcat server
5. edit php.ini(allow_url_include = On)
6. include path of the library in php file.
   try refer this code for more information..
   http://github.com/tsuyu/jasper-report-php-integration

Comment: I prefer this approach myself and I used it successfully in a Project. Considering that it was a small VM with 256 MB of RAM (most of which used by a database), I didn't want to use Tomcat or any full-blown web container, so I used the "little" server included with PHP/Java Bridge: `java -Djava.ext.dirs=. -jar JavaBridge.jar SERVLET_LOCAL:8081 3 JavaBridge.log` Using _java.ext.dirs_ is the only way I've found to use external JAR's (in this case in the local directory "." of _JavaBridge.jar_). Before I was using **java_require**, but it's now unsupported by the latest PJB releases.

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to build/find a java interpreter in php. Or more realistically, ask Java from PHP using Exec()

EDIT

Or share a database connection and create a table for inter-communications. Which has some nice scalability points in its favor.