# How to Integrate Jasper Reports in Codeigniter PHP

Tags: codeigniter, jasper-reports

I have tried below link to integrate jasper report in Codeigniter php

but it doesn't works

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/822686/how-connect-jasper-reports-php-application

Can anybody explain any other method to integrate jasper reports in Codeigniter PHP ?

**EDIT**

Code:

```
<?php 
 require_once APPPATH . "report/vendor/autoload.dist.php"; 
 header('Content-Type: text/html'); 
 use Jaspersoft\Client\Client; 
 $c = new Client( "localhost", "8080", "jasperadmin", "jasperadmin", "/jasperserver-pro", "organization_1" ); 
 $report = $c->reportService()->runReport(APPPATH.'/report/sample_repor‌​t', 'html'); 
 echo $report; 
?>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and be more specific. What doesn't work? Do you see an error? Did you try the very same or a little different?

Comment: I just want to generate pdf reports of my project. so i need jasper report to display my reports. the issue is i don't know how to generate pdf reports using jasper.

Comment: You didn't answer my questions. I am unable to help this way. Showing your code at least would help.

Comment: I have already generated reports using mpdf and tcpdf the next is to i need to generate reports using jasper reports. I don't know how to do this can you explain step by step to integrate jasper in code igniter

Comment: Here is the View file </br><code><?php
require_once APPPATH . "report/vendor/autoload.dist.php";
 
header('Content-Type: text/html');
 
use Jaspersoft\Client\Client;
 
$c = new Client(
        "localhost",
        "8080",
        "jasperadmin",
        "jasperadmin",
        "/jasperserver-pro",
        "organization_1"
      );  
 
$report = $c->reportService()->runReport(APPPATH.'/report/sample_report', 'html');
 
echo $report;  
 
?> </code>

Comment: Please [edit] next time the question. What you are using is code to access Jasperreport Server. Also, you want to access a report in `/report/sample_report`. Both run and exist?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use Jaspersoft Reports, you *cannot* use pre-created PDF files.

The process looks more or less like this:

- Take Jaspersoft Studio to design report (will give jrxml file)
- Upload jrxml file somewhere
- Use some kind of PHP wrapper to create a report *when you need it with fresh data*, like the [Jaspersoft PHP Rest Client](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jrs-rest-php-client). For more explanation see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304023/using-jasper-reports-in-a-php-website)
- *Then* this report can be created for example as a PDF file and provided for downloading

If you already created *and* filled the PDF files, it is more or less a question how to provide the PHP download.