# How to show Jasper Reports in web browser using PHP/Java Bridge?

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I successfully integrated PHP/Java Bridge, and am able to show a Jasper report through Jasper Viewer which is a Swing application component. I just want to show it in a web browser using PHP/Java Bridge.

Code:

```
<?php
    define('JAVA_INC_URL', 'http://localhost:8088/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc');
    require_once(JAVA_INC_URL);
    $system= new Java('java.lang.System');
    $class=new JavaClass('java.lang.Class');
    $class->forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    $driverManager=new JavaClass("java.sql.DriverManager");
    $conn=$driverManager->getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname?user=uname&password=pass");
    $compileManager = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager");
    $viewer = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer");

    $report=$compileManager->compileReport("C:/xampp/htdocs/abc/inventory.jrxml");
    $fillManager = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager");
    $params = new Java("java.util.HashMap");
    $emptyDataSource = new Java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource");
    $printManager=new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager");
    $jasperPrint = $fillManager->fillReport($report, $params, $conn);
    $viewer->viewReport($jasperPrint,false);
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using Jasper reports in a PHP website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304023/using-jasper-reports-in-a-php-website)

Comment: In found these answers before i tried these and successfully integrate jasper reports in php application via bridge but i have just one question how to show it on web browser instead of downloading the file.